# OpenGL to Unity bridge/plugin

Tags: opengl, unity-game-engine

I have an application which is currently using OpenGL to generate and render mesh objects and I would like to pass those objects into Unity, running on the same machine. My application can both run in Windows or Linux.

Would anyone know of a bridge between OpenGL and Unity that would allow me to pass objects and their textures from OpenGL into Unity? I found Syphon (for OSX) but it only allows to share textures between OpenGL and Unity from what I understood.

The application running OpenGL is the one creating the meshes, and not just importing it from a file. Also, since the application is doing other things besides creating the objects, I cant skip it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to clear up a few things first. 
OpenGL is an API used to draw 3D graphics. Unity is a game development software that uses things like OpenGL and DirectX in its architecture. So, the application that you have contains code that reads 3D model files, and uses OpenGL to draw them on screen. If this program that you have is opensource, you can find these 3D model files in a subfolder in the directory of your program. They will be in a format like ".obj" or ".fbx". You can then take those files and import them into Unity. Ofcourse this doesnt work if the OpenGl application you have is not opensource because you wont have access to the 3D files.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Actually my application running OpenGL is actually the one creating the meshes, and not just importing it from a file as you describe. Also, since my application is doing other things besides creating the objects, I cant skip it.

Comment: Then I would recommend implementing a simple OBJ exporter. to do this, just write to a text file: first your vertices like this:  v 0.000000 2.000000 2.000000 (one per line) then your faces f 1 2 3 4 where 1,2,3,4 are indices of the vertex in this mesh. and thats it. save the text file as a ".obj" and unity will be able to import it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I will give it a try! A drawback of this approach I guess is that it may had quite some latency?

Comment: No, as long as you dealing with reasonably sized data set (number of vertices), the process will be fairly fast.